# Manipulating jQuery object without changing the html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-manipulation

I have a variable with a jQuery object, for example:

```
var div = $('#div_element');
```

How can I manipulate ONLY the `div` variable, without changing the `#div_element` itself?

---

I want to do some edits on the `div` variable and to pass it as an argument to a plugin, like this:

```
var el = $('#div');
el.find(':first').remove();
$().popup(el); //I wrote this plugin myself
```

Actually I want to display popup containing the `#div` element (with removed the first "child"), but don't want to change the `#div` element itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to create a copy of the element.

```
var el = $('#div').clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like

```
$().popup($("#div :not(:first-child)"));
```